# How to write stored procedure with if then

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Am new to stored procedures, being familiar with C#.

I need a stored procedure that does this:

```
Select * from dbo.file_map where file_sub_type = @file_sub_type and column_name =  
@column_name and col_num = @col_num
```

If it is found, return true.

if it is not found, Insert table row into error table.

Can I do this in one stored procedure?  Or do I need to create three of them, one to see if the record exists, one to insert row in the error table, and a top level that will be called from C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stored procedure can't "return true"...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.file_map ...rest of your query...)
BEGIN
  RETURN 1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.ErrorTable ...columns... ...values...;
  RETURN 0;
END
```